# How to let Widget PendingIntend re-use existing MainActivity instance?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I am working on an Android 4+ app. The app uses a simple MainActivity that can launch a couple of other Activities. A good example would be a Mail App: The MainActivity shows a list of mail. Additional a ReaderActivity and a ComposeActivity are available. Lets assume, that the MainActivity has some other options, e.g. to show a message box / alert that displays the free space of the mailbox.

So far everything works fine. Know I have created a widget that allows access the "free space" option directly: When the user clicks a button in the widget, this should bring up the MainActiviy showing the "free space" message box.

To solve this I simply added the following `PendingIntent` to the widget button:

```
// In Windget Provider
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ...
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget__content);

    Intent showFreeSpaceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    showFreeSpaceIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.IS_WIDGET_CALL_EXTRA_ID, true);
    PendingIntent showFreeSpacePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, showFreeSpaceIntent , 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_infoButton, showFreeSpacePendingIntent );

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    ...
}


// In MainActiviy
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Boolean isWidgetCall = (intent != null ? intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_WIDGET_CALL_EXTRA_ID, false) : false);

    if (isWidgetCall) ...
}
```

This launches the App with the MainActivity on top showing the desired information.

**The Problem:**

- If the MainActivity is already running a new instance is created on top.
- If another Activity, e.g. ReadMailActivity, is on top, a new MainActivity is created and set on top.

This creates a Activity stack that was never intended. There should only be one instance of MainActivity. If one (ore more) Activitoes is on top, it should be closed to return to the MainActivity which should then show the information.

**How can I build this behaviour?**

Comment: Did you try `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)?

Comment: @ci_ `singleTop` launchMode won't help if there is already another `Activity` on top of `MainActivity` in the existing task stack. Android will still launch another instance of `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'CLEAR_TOP' flag to your `Intent`:

```
Intent showFreeSpaceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
showFreeSpaceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
showFreeSpaceIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.IS_WIDGET_CALL_EXTRA_ID, true);
```

This will remove any existing instances of `MainActivity` and any other activities that are on top of that, then create a new instance of `MainActivity`.

Note: This will only work if your `MainActivity` is always active (not finished) in the task stack. If your `MainActivity` calls `finish()` when launching other activites, this will not work.